# How to use this in ffi

Tags: assembly, lua, jit, luajit

```
std::string __cpuid()
{
    char VendorName[49] = {0};
    char VendorID[13] = {0};
    unsigned int a, b, c, d;
__asm xor EBX, EBX;
__asm xor ECX, ECX;
__asm xor EDX, EDX;
__asm mov EAX, 0x80000002;
__asm cpuid;
__asm mov a, EAX;
__asm mov b, EBX;
__asm mov c, ECX;
__asm mov d, EDX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 0], EAX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 4], EBX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 8], ECX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 12], EDX;
__asm mov EAX, 0x80000003;
__asm cpuid;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 16], EAX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 20], EBX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 24], ECX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 28], EDX;
__asm mov EAX, 0x80000004;
__asm cpuid;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 32], EAX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 36], EBX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 40], ECX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorName + 44], EDX;
__asm mov EAX, 0x00000000;
__asm cpuid;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorID + 0], EBX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorID + 4], EDX;
__asm mov DWORD PTR [VendorID + 8], ECX;
__asm mov EAX, 0x80000004;
    strcat(VendorName, " ");
    strcat(VendorName, VendorID);
    return string(VendorName);
}
```

Sirs, how to use this in ffi lua? I'm bad in ffi

I tried to use ffi.cdef, but compiller asked me: declaration specifier expected near 'std'

I tried to use a lot of everything, but im so noob

Comment: What FFI? Are you using LuaJIT? In that case, that's not how the FFI works at all. You're supposed to write your C functions *in C* and compile them to a dynamic library. FFI only allows you to *access* those functions from the library in an easy way, but you can't write new code.

Comment: Throw that code into a `.c` file, remove the C++ specific stuff, feed it through the compiler of your choice (CGG is always a good recommendation) and be sure to look up how to tell it you want a dynamic library, not an executable program. If you have trouble with that, feel free to ask.

Comment: Also make sure to explain exactly what your problem is and what you've tried. The exact Lua version (5.1, 5.3, LuaJIT, etc.) is very useful because the answer may differ from version to version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works on LuaJIT x86
(It doesn't work if LuaJIT was built using MS VisualStudio, use MinGW)

```
assert(jit.arch =='x86')

local ffi = require("ffi")
local qwords = ffi.typeof("uint64_t[?]")
local dwords = ffi.typeof("uint32_t *")
-- cpuid_EAX_EDX = push EBX / cpuid / pop EBX / ret
local cpuid_EAX_EDX = ffi.cast("__cdecl uint64_t (*)(uint32_t)", "\x53\x0F\xA2\x5B\xC3")
-- cpuid_EBX_ECX = push EBX / cpuid / xchg EAX,ECX / xchg EAX,EDX / xchg EAX,EBX / pop EBX / ret
local cpuid_EBX_ECX = ffi.cast("__cdecl uint64_t (*)(uint32_t)", "\x53\x0F\xA2\x91\x92\x93\x5B\xC3")

local function cpuid(n)
   local arr = ffi.cast(dwords, qwords(2, cpuid_EAX_EDX(n), cpuid_EBX_ECX(n)))
   return ffi.string(arr, 4), ffi.string(arr + 2, 4), ffi.string(arr + 3, 4), ffi.string(arr + 1, 4)
end

local s1 = ""
for n = 0x80000002, 0x80000004 do
   local eax, ebx, ecx, edx = cpuid(n)
   s1 = s1..eax..ebx..ecx..edx
end
s1 = s1:gsub("^%s+", ""):gsub("%z+$", "")  -- remove leading spaces and trailing zeroes

local eax, ebx, ecx, edx = cpuid(0)
local s2 = ebx..edx..ecx
s2 = s2:gsub("^%s+", ""):gsub("%z+$", "")  -- remove leading spaces and trailing zeroes

print(s1.." "..s2)  -- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz GenuineIntel
```