# how to use FFI::typeof

Tags: php, ffi, php-ffi

I was trying to port [How to use this in ffi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002471/569976) to PHP to bolster my understanding of FFI and I'm stuck on the fourth line - `local qwords = ffi.typeof("uint64_t[?]")`. How do I do that in PHP?

Here's what I tried:

```
FFI::typeof('uint64_t[?]');
```

Gives a "*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: FFI::typeof(): Argument #1 ($ptr) must be of type FFI\CData, string given*" error.

```
FFI::typeof(new FFI\CData('uint64_t[?]'));
```

Gives a "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Instantiation of FFI\CData is not allowed*" error.

So how do I do that in PHP?

Comment: I know nothing about FFI, but [`FFI::new`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ffi.new.php) returns a `CData` instance, so maybe try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a variable-length array type with PHP's FFI library, you need define the element type first, then you can create an array type by specifying the dimensions:

```
$uint64_t = FFI::type('uint64_t');
$uint64_t_4 = FFI::arrayType($uint64_t, [4]);
```

Or directly specify the dimension:

```
$uint64_t_4 = FFI::type('uint64_t[4]');
```

To create an array of the type, use `FFI::new`:

```
$arr64_4 = FFI::new($uint64_t_4);
$arr64_4[0] = 0x200000001;
```

Then you can cast the array to another type like this:

```
$arr32_8 = FFI::cast('uint32_t[8]', $arr64_4);
```