# FFI::cast() with the second parameter as a string

Tags: php, ffi, php-ffi

In [How to use this in ffi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002471/569976) there's this:

```
local cpuid_EAX_EDX = ffi.cast("__cdecl uint64_t (*)(uint32_t)", "\x53\x0F\xA2\x5B\xC3")
```

My question is...  how do I port that to PHP? This doesn't work:

```
$cpuid_EAX_EDX = FFI::cast('__cdecl uint64_t (*)(uint32_t)', "\x53\x0F\xA2\x5B\xC3");
```

But per https://www.php.net/manual/en/ffi.cast.php I wouldn't expect that to work and, lo and behold, it doesn't. It gets me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: FFI::cast(): Argument #2 ($ptr) must be of type FFI\CData, string
```

Doing `FFI::new("\x53\x0F\xA2\x5B\xC3")` doesn't work as that, by itself, gets me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\ParserException: unexpected character 'escape_char(ch)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you asked is more like a syntactic sugar for:

1. Allocate a block of memory
2. Write some bytes into it
3. Convert it to a function pointer

I'm not sure if there is such a shortened form in PHP, but I can provide an equivalent process:

```
$p = FFI::addr(FFI::new('uint8_t[5]'));
FFI::memcpy($p, "\x53\x0F\xA2\x5B\xC3", 5);
$cpuid_EAX_EDX = FFI::cast('__cdecl uint64_t (*)(uint32_t)', $p);
echo $cpuid_EAX_EDX(0);
```

---

There is another issue here, the original answer said:

> This code works on LuaJIT x86
> (It doesn't work if LuaJIT was built using MS VisualStudio, use MinGW)

To be honest, I doubt about this. Since Windows XP, Windows has prohibited execution on the heap, and this restriction is enabled by default for 32-bit programs. I believe that even for programs compiled with mingw, it should not be an exception.

Also if you want to run these assembly codes in a 64-bit program, you need to use the following Windows APIs to allocate memory.

```
$ffi = FFI::cdef("
    void* HeapCreate(uint32_t flOptions, size_t dwInitialSize, size_t dwMaximumSize);
    void* HeapAlloc(void* hHeap, uint32_t dwFlags, size_t dwBytes);",
    'kernel32.dll');
$h = $ffi->HeapCreate(0x00040000, 5, 5);
$p = $ffi->HeapAlloc($h, 0, 5);
```